# How to return a 2 dimensional vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a function that creates a 2D vector

```
void generate(int n)
{
   vector< vector<int> > V (n, vector<int>(1 << n , 0 ));
   .......

}//n is used to determine the size of vector
```

Now, I need to return the created vector to use it in another function .If I did

```
return V ;
```

it will be wrong because V is a local variable but I can't define V outside the function because this functions defines the size of V . What should I do ?

Comment: just out of curiosity: do you need to write your own generator "alg"? Why not use std::generate_n?

Comment: This is not the whole function , the rest of the function generates a truth table .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can `return V` with no issues - it will return a copy of the local variable. Issues only arise when you return a *reference* or *pointer* to a variable with local scope; when the function ends, the local variable falls out of scope and is destroyed and the reference/pointer is no longer valid.

Alternatively, you can accept a reference to a vector as your argument, write to it and return void:

```
void generate(int n, std::vector< std::vector<int> >& vec) {
    vec.resize(n, std::vector<int>(1 << n, 0));
}

int main() {
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > v;
    generate(10, v);
}
```

This is faster than returning a copy of the local member, which can be expensive for large objects such as multi-dimensional vectors.

Comment: V is big , isn't it a bad practice to return a copy . Also , the size of the vector is determined *inside* the function so how can I pass it to the function and redefine its size ??

Comment: @Ahmed See updated answer. It's only bad practice to return-by-value (meaning by copying a variable) if you discover it's noticeable affecting performance.  It looks like you're probably only calling this method once to initialize your data, if that's the case there will be no measurable difference in performance.

Comment: As Job points out, you should be sure to `clear()` the vector if you're not sure that it will be empty.

Comment: It's also definitely worth noting RVO and NRVO. These compiler optimizations will effectively remove copies in returning by value by changing it to being the posted form of generate. You should always just return local variables by value, and manually do this optimization if profiling reveals a problem.

Comment: So RVO and NRVO eliminates the necessity of pass by reference in my case ?

Answer (score 6):

```
vector<vector<int> > generate(int n)
{
    vector<vector<int> > v(n, vector<int>(1 << n, 0));
    //...
    return v;
}
```

The return value is a copy of the local variable `v` so there is no problem at all.

If you're concerned about copying the vector, maybe you could do something like this:

```
void generate(int n, vector<vector<int> >& v)
{
    v.clear(); //not necessary if you're sure it's empty
    v.resize(n, vector<int>(1 << n, 0));
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like we do for other,we can do that here also.See my code for better explanation I have given my code for matrix multiplication in which i have made a function for it and returned a matrix as a **2D vector**.
`

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector<vector<int>> mul(vector<vector<int>> a,vector<vector<int>> b)
{
    int n=a.size();
    int k=a[0].size();
    int m=b[0].size();
    vector<vector<int>> c(n,vector<int> (m,0));
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            c[i][j]=0;
            for(int m=0;m<k;m++)
            {
                c[i][j]+=(a[i][m]*b[m][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return c;
}
int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> l={{1,2}};
    vector<vector<int>> r={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
     vector<vector<int>> m;
    m=mul(l,r);
    
    for(int i=0;i<m.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m[i].size();j++)
        {
            cout<<m[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: The parameters a and b should be passed by const reference, to avoid dynamic memory allocations during the copies.

Comment: It's up to you whatever you do with that I have just given a simple example where function is returning 2D vector.

Answer (score 0):

if the vector is small, just return it by value, it will be copied.
if the vector is large, the caller can pass the dest vector by reference.

Comment: I decide the size of the vector from inside this function .

Answer (score 0):

As alternative to other answers you can return pointer to heap allocated vector. For securing from memory leaks you can use "move constructor" idiom.

```
typedef auto_ptr<vector<vector<int> > > vector_ptr;
vector_ptr generate(int n)
{
   vector_ptr V(new vector<vector<int> >(n, vector<int>(1 << n , 0 )));
   return V;
}

// ...

vector_ptr V(generate(some_number));
```

This idiom can be used for any "heavy" object. If you whant to prolonge lifetime of returned object you can assign it to shared_ptr (as example boost::shared_ptr). But I think it is better return copy whenever it is possible, for minimizing complexity of your code.